# python setup tools - install a sub package from within a project

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

I have two projects (trysetup1 and trysetup2) with the following structure:

[image]

I want to pip install package1 and use module1 from project trysetup2

my setup.py that under package1 looks like this:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="common",
    version="1.0.2",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

the way I want to use module1 is like this `from package1.module1 import ClassOne` because I still need to use it from package2

when trying to import from module2 it works just fine

[image]

but when trying to use it from module3 (in the different project after pip installing it) i'm having "*Unresolved reference 'package1'*" problem

[image]

I know I'm able to use module1 by putting it inside another package under package1 but I need this exact stracture in order to use it from the rest of the project 'trysetup1'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer was found here:

https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/examples.html

actually, all I needed to do was to change my setup.py file to look like this:

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="common",
    version="1.0.2",
    package_dir={'package1': ''},
    packages=['package1'],
)
```

by adding **package_dir** param, setup function tells all files under my root directory (package1) to be under package1 directory and by adding **packages** param it distributes *package1* package and then if you go to:

/..../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/common-1.0.2-py3.8.egg-info/top_level.txt

you'll see the following content:

[image]